# SQL Server Dynamic Pivot Table - Column Name Duplicate

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am attempting to Pivot a table passed in as a UDT.. Column 1 will have duplicate values and Column 2 will have different values (example below). I am hoping for the Column Name to be set as Phone Number and the two Values under the Phone Number column.

```
    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    --Temp Table to act as UDT for ease of testing
    DECLARE @udt TABLE (DatabaseFieldName nvarchar(50), Value nvarchar(50))

    INSERT INTO @udt VALUES('PhoneNumber','01234567890')
    INSERT INTO @udt VALUES('PhoneNumber','09876543210')

    --Preview of table before Pivot
    select * from @udt

    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
    DatabaseFieldName nvarchar(50),
    Value nvarchar(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT DatabaseFieldName, Value 
    FROM @udt

    SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(DatabaseFieldName) + ',' FROM (select distinct DatabaseFieldName from #temp) as temp
    SELECT @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) -- Trims ',' at the end

    SET @query =
    '
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT DatabaseFieldName, Value
        FROM #temp
    ) AS SRC
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN(Value) for DatabaseFieldName in (' + @cols + ')
    ) AS PivotTable';

    execute(@query)
    DROP TABLE #temp
```

### Example of current & desired results

```
Data as it comes in:

DatabaseFieldName | Value
--------------------------------
PhoneNumber       | 01234567890
PhoneNumber       | 09876543210

Outcome I am hoping to get:

PhoneNumber
------------
01234567890
09876543210

What I am currently getting:

PhoneNumber
------------
01234567890
```

At the moment the second number is being ignored due to the use of distinct in the select statement, however an error is thrown if distinct is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the values that you want in the pivoted column PhoneNumbers? If so, you can just select the phone numbers themselves with an alias. E.g

```
SELECT Value As PhoneNumber
FROM (either @UDT or #temp)
WHERE DatabaseFieldName = 'PhoneNumber'
```

Unless there is a requirement I'm missing here, this would do everything you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not due to DISTINCT, it is because of using MIN(Value) , it gets the first one.
Let's say you had another set of rows

```
INSERT INTO @udt VALUES('Name','Hello')
INSERT INTO @udt VALUES('Name','Test')
```

Now the result set of your dynamic SQL will look like this.

```
Name    PhoneNumber
Hello   01234567890
```

Having said that PIVOT can be used only with aggregate functions, you will get error if MIN is removed. You might have to think of other options for getting desired results such as using case if needed for multiple fields

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DatabaseFieldName = 'PhoneNumber' THEN Value END AS PhoneNumber,
       CASE WHEN DatabaseFieldName = 'Name' THEN Value END AS Name
       FROM @udt
```